# Local Postgres database to Google Cloud PostgreSQL Github

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I would like to build a Google Cloud PostgreSQL database using the instructions [here](https://github.com/mcekovic/tennis-crystal-ball/issues/232)

I was able to successfully create the Postgres databases with appropriate tables and views locally.

What do I need to do in order to get the data on Google Cloud PostgreSQL? My goal is to have remote access to this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options, The first one is use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) as is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-proxy-test). As the shared links say, the Cloud SQL Proxy provides secure access to your instances without the need for Authorized networks or for configuring SSL.

On the other hand, the second option is only to configure access to your instance under Authorized networks using or not SSL. The complete steps are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#mysqlclient)

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick. Do you have any idea why data is loading from my local machine to GCP very slowly? I am using the non-SSL option.

Comment: Where is your Cloud SQL instance located? from where you are trying to access it? 

As this documentation says https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/faq#using-cloud-sql-with-app-engine "larger distance between your Cloud SQL instance and your App Engine application causes greater latency for connections to the database" In this case is talking about App Engine and Cloud SQL, but this same rule applies to all connection ways.

Comment: Another cause of this could be if your database is constrained on memory or CPU. As you can see here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues#tips
For performance-intensive workloads, your instance should have at least 60 GB of memory.

Comment: A third cause could be due to network issues, does your network  is working right?
If none of the above apply, I would recommend you to open a case with the support team in order for them to check your instance in a deeper way.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to Cloud SQL from a local test environment using cloud sql proxy. See [quickstart-proxy-test](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-proxy-test).

The workflow is:

Your Application(Running Locally) => cloud sql proxy (Running locally) => GCP remote Cloud SQL service

Comment: thank you very much! I greatly appreciate your help.